# Want to create react native app.. need some inputs on DB option

Tags: database, react-native, mobile-application

I want to create a new shopping kind of app using react native (Expo). Need few details like,

1. Which DB is better to use (I'm familiar with SQL)
2. From react native itself, can we connect to the DB or do we need to use other medium to connect
   to DB and then call the APIs from ReactNative?
3. If I use dotnet as medium to connect to DB and call dotnet API from ReactNative, how difficult
   it will be while publishing the app?

Can someone please elaborate on these points, as I'm fairly new to ReactNative and mobile app development.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It depends on what are you trying to accomplish. Would you like low cost at the start? Is performance a critical feature for you? Do you have enough time to build the backend?

Comment: @FrancescoClementi : Thanks for the response.                                                            
    1. Time - Yes I do have ample time for development.                                                                
    2. Performace - Medium performance will do                                                                   
    3. Cost - Low cost at start would be better

Comment: Ok, so you need a mandatory backend. From my point of you I prefer a full stack javascript solution (mongodb+nodejs+react native), but even with mysql/postgresql is ok (don't know .NET and totally depends on your data model). However I suggest you a PaaS solution such as Firebase. you don't need a backend and with low usage you don't pay anything.

Comment: when I have enough time I'll build an answer

Comment: @FrancescoClementi: Thanks a lot for your responses, it helps. I'll explore more on the options that you have mentioned here and decide based on that. Moreover, I've zero knowledge about Firebase. Will see how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no correct answer on your question.

If you don't need really critical performance requirements a lot of solution could fit your request.

The most common stack for mobile development are:

**MERN stack:**

MongoDB, ExpressJS, ReactJS, NodeJS
https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-create-your-first-mern-mongodb-express-js-react-js-and-node-js-stack-7e8b20463e66

*PROS*

1. Full stack javascript solution
2. Flexible data model with non relational db mongodb
3. Fast learning curve

**CONS**

1. Could require system administration
2. Could require architecture knowledge
3. Require nodejs knowledge
4. Costs
5. High TTM if you are alone (Time to market)
6. Require IT security knowledge

Note: you can replace MongoDB with PostgresSQL if your data model doesn't require flexibility and you have more experience.

This solution require a backend server which came with a cost and system knowledge (do you need a scalable architecture?), you can opt for example for Google App Engine (PaaS server) with a standard environment to reduce cost with less performance or flexible environment with more cost and good performance.

**FIREBASE**

Firebase is a platform developed by Google for creating mobile and web applications. Is a BaaS (Backend as a Service), so you don't need a backend, it give you really nice free usage (you won't have cost during development) and give all the complex part as a service such as authentication (username/password, social login, phone login, reset password ecc..), real time non relational database, storage, cloud functions and much more.

Is just a framework that you need to integrate in your app with easy configuration, easy query and good documentation.

The cons is that you will be locked with firebase as a provider.

DotNet solution is not really common on a full stack mobile development, is more an enterprise solution.

If you are searching for a fast learning curve and an easy development environment, the best solution is ExpoJS (instead of react native) and Firebase.

Comment: Thanks much for your time.. can you also please throw some light on using SQLite with react native, it's pros and cons

Comment: sqllite with react-native is a db on the smartphone. There is no remote data, no sync, ecc... usually it's used for offline applications or similar

Comment: cool.. got some idea about few points on DBs for react.. will explore and work on it.. thanks again

Comment: Your views about this approach please?  https://levelup.gitconnected.com/react-native-mongodb-stitch-building-a-crud-application-without-a-server-3e4ae0b34d67

Comment: You will still be blocked with a Backend as a Service provider, but in that case you will also need to manage authentication ecc.  For me it's an ugly middle choice between a full stack solution and a complete Backend as a Service. It seems that you would like a "own firebase solution", so you can check this: https://parseplatform.org/

Comment: ok.. have made up my mind to go with Firebase, will see how it goes, hope no blockers inbetween.. will be back to disturb you, if any issues. :)